# How to store a sprite in a global variable using c# script after touch event in unity for a 2D game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am new to unity and want to store a sprite in a global variable to access in other scene after touch event occurs.  Any idea in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: look up the *static* keyword

Comment: my question was about Unity so don't suggest me other tools.

Comment: I'm referring to static fields: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose an approach to solve this case.

Define a sprite manager class "MySpriteManager" as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MySpriteManager {
    private static Dictionary<string, Sprite> spriteMap = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();

    public static void AddSprite(string key, Sprite value) {
        spriteMap.add(key, value);
    }

    public static Sprite GetSprite(string key) {
        return spriteMap[key];
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to save a sprite instance for future uses,

```
MySpriteManager.AddSprite("my_sprite_key", my_sprite_instance);
```

To retrieve a previously saved sprite instance,

```
Sprite savedSprite = MySpriteManager.GetSprite("my_sprite_key");
```

Hopefully the idea is illustrated clearly enough.

Comment: Some one suggested me to keep all static variables in AppController and then using the Physics2d.OvelapPoint(ontouch) function to save the value and then use this value to access through other script. is this a good approach or the one you told so?

Comment: sorry, i dont think i understand your algorithm. how is using physics functions related to accessing sprite instances?